# How can I prevent flashing of entities in VSCode highlight when I move the cursor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, when you are over a word or text string, it highlights it with a grey (in my theme color) background. This is all nice, but the problem is that it removes the highlight when I move the cursor, even when I am still on the same word. This makes the word flash on and off every time I press the left or right cursor key, which is very annoying.

Is there a way to keep the highlighting when I am moving over the same word, or alternatively, is there a way to disable the highlighting altogether?

Comment: This doesn't happens for me. Maybe i mis-understood your question. Can you share a gif image that shows what you are talking about?

Comment: When you go with the text cursor on a variable, does it highlights it after approx 0.1 seconds? If yes, does it go off when you move left or right but still on the same variable?

Comment: That's exactly what i tried when i first saw your question; no, highlight does not go off for me when i move the cursor on the highlighted variable using the left/right arrow keys.

Comment: @yousaf I found it's because of the vim extension. No idea how to fix it. I'll post a bug report there